# Why do Djinn seek to marry humans

Tags: spirituality

Why do Djinn marry humans, I have read that many Djinn serve God, but why do they seek to marry us.

Comment: Do they? Note that it is disputed whether marriage\intimacy between jinn and humans is possible. Further there is dispute on whether it is permissible. In any case it is a rare occurrence if not non-existent. If it happens then maybe the reason is the same as that of marriage between humans i.e. attraction towards some quality. And when done by the evil jinn (devils) it could also be because of some nefarious purposes such as causing mischief.

Comment: That’s not an answer